What to set as title when title is large for SEO / google?
I have a situation where I am rendering books/texts in many languages, scripts, and versions. For example, the Tibetan book "Kangyur" comes in 3 flavors, one being the "Dege" Kangyur. The Dege Kangyur comes in many copies with slight variations in the text, call them c1, c2, and "wikisource" (the wikisource version). Sort of as if there are many Latin translations of the bible.
Then there are Tibetan language versions, and English versions. The Tibetan version can be written in Tibetan script, or romanized in multiple different ways (such as the Wylie romanization scheme).
So I have at least this many pages:

Dege Kangyur in Tibetan Script, Tibetan Language, Wikisource Version
Dege Kangyur in Latin Script, Tibetan Language, Wylie Scheme, Wikisource Version
Dege Kangyur in Latin Script, Tibetan Language, Scheme 2, Wikisource Version
Dege Kangyur in Latin Script, English Language, Translation X
Possibly more down the road.

In addition, I have pages for subsections of the book collection:

Perfection of Wisdom in 10,000 Lines, in Tibetan, from Dege Kangyur, Tibetan Script, Tibetan Language, Wikisource Version

Titles start to get very long.
So should those be the titles? Or how long should a title be? How much should go into a title? What if all were just named Dege Kangyur in Tibetan, and leave out the details from Google SEO perspective? Could that stuff go into the meta description instead, or should it go into the title, even though it makes it long?
Basically, are long titles good? If not good, acceptable? What is the ideal to do here?

Long titles are valid HTML, and thus acceptable.
https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html
They're not ideal, but shouldn't harm SEO too much (Google tend to pick their own title rather than truncate nowadays)

I would choose a detailed title above a short title. Titles should be as unique as possible. But, trying to predict, or guess, how search engines work is difficult. Not only is it difficult to know what the rules are, the rules also keep change all the time. Just make sure your pages are technically good, of high quality, and offer your visitors something unique, and search engines will pick up on that.
